# C++ : adding an object to a set

Tags: c++, inheritance, set

I am having trouble with adding an object to a set.

I use two classes in a header file, one for employees and a second one for managers. In the manager class I want to create a set of employees by adding employees who are subordinates for a particular manager. First I create a empty set for which I can add objects by calling a function.

It looks as follows:

header file

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_HH
#define EMPLOYEE_HH

#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;

class Employee {
    public:
      // Constructor
      Employee(const char* name, double salary) :
         _name(name),
         _salary(salary) {
      }

      // Accessors
      const char* name() const { 
         return _name.c_str() ;
      }
      double salary() const {
         return _salary ;
      }

    private:
      string _name ;
      double _salary ;

} ;

class Manager : public Employee {
    public:
      //Constructor
      Manager(const char* _name, double _salary):
         Employee(_name, _salary),
         _subordinates() {
      }

      // Accessors/Modifiers
      void addSubordinate(Employee& empl) {
         _subordinates.insert(empl) ;     // Error: no macthing function call for .insert()    
      }

    private:
      set<Employee*> _subordinates ;        

} ;

#endif
```

Main script

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Employee.hh"

using namespace std ;

int main() {

    Employee emp = ("David", 10000) ;

    Manager mgr = ("Oscar", 20000) ;

    mgr.addSubordinate(emp);    

    return 0;

}
```

When compiling I get the error that no matching function can be called for `_subordinates.insert(empl)`.

Comment: Obviously `Employee` won't match `Employee*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element's type of `set` is `Employee*`, but you're inserting `Employee`.

You might change `_subordinates.insert(empl);` to `_subordinates.insert(&empl);`.

(Changing the type of `_subordinates` from `set<Employee*>` to `set<Employee>` could fix the compiler error too, but it seems doesn't match the request.)

Note as @KenmanTsang pointed, using pointer got from stack variable might be dangerous. Consider about using [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) with `new`, such as `std::set<std::unique_ptr<Employee>> _subordinates;`.

BTW:

```
Employee emp = ("David", 10000) ;
Manager mgr = ("Oscar", 20000) ;
```

should be

```
Employee emp ("David", 10000) ;
Manager mgr ("Oscar", 20000) ;
```

or (since c++11)

```
Employee emp = {"David", 10000} ;
Manager mgr = {"Oscar", 20000} ;
```

Comment: That's only part of the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I found this strange because according to https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html, insert() takes const value_type& as an argument and in my function I define empl as Employee&. Also as juanchopanze said, I get other compiler errors now so there are more things I have to work on apparently

Comment: for this line -> _subordinates.insert(&empl);    The empl will be invalid as soon as the scope of the variable is ended. so I dont think this simple fix solve the problem.

Comment: @user_537 Sorry can't get what you mean, defining `empl` as `Employee&` or `const Employee&` doesn't matter in your code. And note if you change the type of `_subordinates` to `set<Employee>` it should work fine too.

Comment: @KenmanTsang It just works for the code OP posted here. Since `mgr` and `emp` are in the same scope (i.e. in `main()`) it should be fine.

Comment: I got your point. But it will introduce a hidden issue to the class. I suggest you should include the risk into you solution.

Comment: @user_537 I updated my answer, it might fix the errors.

Comment: @ songyuanyao, you are completely right. I also entirely overlooked how I created the objects in my main file where I used emp = () and mgr = () instead of emp() and mgr(). I guess this happens if you stare too long at a problem and don't see the obvious mistakes anymore.

Comment: @user_537 Time for coffee. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can either fix by

a)

```
// Accessors/Modifiers
void addSubordinate(Employee& empl) {
    _subordinates.insert(new Employee(empl));
}
```

pros. Easy to fix the problem.

pros. No matter the caller object invalided or not. The copy you saved is safe

cons. You need to do your own memory management. delete all objects in ~Manager();

b)

```
private:
    set<Employee> _subordinates;
```

pros. No need to alter the functions

pros. Auto memory management done by compiler

cons. invoke too much copying with Employee class ( while insertion and retrieval case )